In neo4j cypher, how to use Relationship properties in RelationshipChain for filtering query?
I have created a RelationshipChain in Neo4j Cypher, and I want to filter the query using the properties of the relationships in the chain. However, I am unable to access or retrieve the relationships properly. Are there alternative ways to implement this filtering?
Relationship relationship;
RelationshipChain r = null;
int i =0;
for (RelationshipChainRowDTO chainRowDTO : chainRowDTOS) {
    Node tmpNode =  Cypher.node(chainRowDTO.getConceptionKindName());
    String relationNamed = "r" + i++;
    if (Objects.isNull(r)) {
        r = relationship.relationshipWith(tmpNode, Relationship.Direction.UNI).named(relationNamed);
    } else {
        r = r.relationshipWith(tmpNode, Relationship.Direction.UNI).named(relationNamed);
       // I want to filter by the Relationship property here, but I can't get the current Relationship
    }
}

